# Cuando dejan un campo vacio la informacion no se envia

Tags: php, msql

Al enviar el formulario cuando se deja un campo vació no se logra hacer la validación de datos al menos que se llenen todos los campos, ya tengo varios campos obligatorios pero también tengo campos que el usuario tiene la opción de dejarlos vacíos pero cuando lo hace los datos no se llegan a capturar en la base de datos .

Para entrar en contexto comparto el código de captura de datos que creo relevante, el código del formulario no lo comparto ya que me parece que no es necesario hacerlo :

```
<?php include_once('config.php');
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']) and $_REQUEST['submit']!=""){
    extract($_REQUEST);
    if($nombre==""){
        header('location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?msg=un'); 
        exit;
    }elseif($cedula==""){
        header('location:'.$_SERVER ['PHP_SELF'].'?msg=ue');
        exit;
    }elseif($whatsapp==""){
        header('location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?msg=up');
        exit;
    }
    elseif($celular==""){
        header('location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?msg=up');
        exit;
    }
    elseif($correo==""){
        header('location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?msg=up');
        exit;
    }
    elseif($seguro==""){
        header('location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?msg=up');
        exit;
    }
    elseif($enfermo==""){
        header('location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?msg=up');
        exit;
    }
    elseif($discapacitado==""){
        header('location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?msg=up');
        exit;
    }
    elseif($covid19==""){
        header('location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?msg=up');
        exit;
    }
    else{
        
        $userCount  =   $db->getQueryCount('users','id');
        if($userCount[0]['total']<20){
            $data   =   array(
                            'nombre'=>$nombre,
                            'cedula'=>$cedula,
                            'whatsapp'=>$whatsapp,
                            'celular'=>$celular,
                            'correo'=>$correo,
                            'seguro'=>$seguro,
                            'enfermo'=>$enfermo,
                            'discapacitado'=>$discapacitado,
                            'covid19'=>$covid19,
                            
                            
                        );
            $insert =   $db->insert('users',$data);
            if($insert){
                header('location:agregar-familia.php?msg=ras');
                exit;
            }else{
                header('location:agregar-familia.php?msg=rna');
                exit;
            }
        }else{
            header('location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?msg=dsd');
            exit;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Primero que nada advertirte sobre `extract()` puede ser peligroso usarla para procear datos de usuario ($_REQUEST) ya que puede sobreescribir otras variables existentes. Por otro lado, es necesario que incluyas el formulario ya que no hay manera de saber que datos podrian llegar a dar problemas sin ello. La redireccion puede ser una pista viendo el parametro `msg=??`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como te dice [F.Igor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/32292/f-igor) ese uso de extract es peligroso. Como mínimo, si renombro un input de texto como "db" voy a pisar la conexión que declaraste en `config.php`.

En segundo lugar, la estructura de tu formulario sí es relevante. Si estás usando checkboxes debes tener en cuenta que no marcarlos no envía un "false" ni un "0". Simplemente no envía ese parámetro.

Si, por ejemplo, "covid19" es un checkbox y la persona envía el formulario sin haber marcado esa casilla, en tu backend luego del extract al llegar a

```
elseif($covid19==""){
    header('location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?msg=up');
    exit;
}
```

se gatilla un E_NOTICE

```
 Notice: Undefined variable: covid19 in ...
```

Pero a menos que tengas "display_errors" encendido eso no lo estás viendo. Como sea, tu flujo llega hasta ese `if` en donde se hace una coerción implícita de tipos luego de lo cual tanto la variable indefinida como el string vacío se evalúan como FALSE. Acto seguido el usuario es redirigido.

¿Qué haría en tu caso?

**Primero, sacaría ese extract** y obtendría las variables a través de las llaves del request. Para todas las que sean obligatorias puedes ejecutar `isset` en una sola llamada

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']) && $_REQUEST['submit']!=""){
  if(!isset(
    $_REQUEST['nombre'],
    $_REQUEST['cedula'],
    $_REQUEST['whatsapp'],
    $_REQUEST['celular'],
    $_REQUEST['correo'],
    $_REQUEST['seguro'],
    $_REQUEST['enfermo'],
    $_REQUEST['discapacitado'],
    $_REQUEST['covid19']
  )) {
    // faltan datos
    header('location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?msg=up');
    exit; 
  }

}
```

y a la hora de insertar

```
$data   =   [
    'nombre'=>$_REQUEST['nombre'],
    'cedula'=>$_REQUEST['cedula'],
    'whatsapp'=>$_REQUEST['whatsapp'],
    'celular'=>$_REQUEST['celular'],
    'correo'=>$_REQUEST['correo'],
    'seguro'=>$_REQUEST['seguro'],
    'enfermo'=>$_REQUEST['enfermo'],
    'discapacitado'=>$_REQUEST['discapacitado'],
    'covid19'=>$_REQUEST['covid19']
];
```

**Segundo**:

En el formulario, donde tenga checkboxes, pondré un campo hidden con el valor por defecto que es lo que se enviará cuando el usuario no marque la casilla

```js
const formulario=document.querySelector("#ejemplo");
formulario.addEventListener("submit", (event)=> {
  console.log(formulario.serialize());
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
}, false);

document.querySelector("#enviar").addEventListener("click", (event)=> {
  console.log($(formulario).serializeArray());
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
}, false);
```

```css
#ejemplo {
width:50%;
float:left;
}
#ejemplo label {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="ejemplo">
  <label>
  <input type="hidden" value="0" name="enfermo" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="enfermo" /> enfermo ? (default 0)
  </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="discapacitado" /> discapacitado ? (sin default!)
  </label>
  
</form>
<button id="enviar">probar</button>
```

Cuando se marca el primer checkbox, en este ejemplo, se verá que el formulario envía tanto el default (0) como el valor del checkbox (1). Ya que ambos tienen el mismo nombre, el backend toma en cuenta el último, que en buenas cuentas "pisa" al default